# Include authentication MVC4 project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I'm in a trouble, I guess.

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 4 project without default authentication, well, my problem now is add an authentication to this project, note, I've been working it since four months, then I have a system working, but I don't have authentication.

So my question is: **What must I do to achieve this authentication?**

PS.: If you need some code or config file ask in comments, I've no idea what I must to paste here.

Comment: Why don't you create a new blank project using the authentication template that comes with Visual Studio and figure out how that works? It will stand you in good stead in the future to know it from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

- you have to add AccountController and
- views from Account folder in Views
- you need _LoginPartial.cshtml
- also _Layout.cshtml looks differently (because references to _LoginPartials)

Remember about making sure, if connection string in WebConfig file was created correctly.

When it comes to references, use following:

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin

The question is - do you want to use built-in external login facilities? (via Twitter, Facebook, Google etc.) Because there are more namespaces required in that kind of situation.